# Paying using PayPal account without redirection to PayPal's website

Tags: c#, api, paypal

Let me explain my situation.  I have a mobile application which allows the user to enter his credit card details and make a payment using the PayPal Direct Payment API.  The mobile application does not operate using the browser but works via a web services framework.

I was thinking of adding another option.  The user enters his PayPal username and password into my mobile application.  The mobile application should then make a request to PayPal, with the buyer's PayPal username and password passed as parameters in addition to the transaction details.  However, the buyer should always stay on my mobile application.  He should not be redirected to PayPal's website or any other website.

Is this even possible?  If yes, what version of the PayPal API do I need to use?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible, as a PayPal Client should never have access to the Username/Password, and the user always confirms the payment on the PayPal website itself

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Paul :)  That's what I thought as well.